# Getting started with OpenFire, XMPP, and PHP

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

I've been tasked with creating an IM app for IOS. I currently have an XCode programmer creating the app itself and we have selected OpenFire for the XMPP server. The only issue is that I have never done anything closely resembling a chat program before and am having difficulty getting things rolling. I have installed OpenFire and have it working correctly and have the database setup. Now I have to figure out where to go from here. I have no idea how to make an XMPP request nor do I know how to write a client. I am a seasoned PHP vet and am using PHP to write an API for our chat app but I dont really know if I should try going the route where I use PHP to make XMPP requests or if the XCode programmer should do that. In any case I need to read up on how to make XMPP requests in general and then of course figure out how to do it in my language of choice. I am really hoping to stick to what I know with PHP. It seems most of the prefab XMPP clients are Java based which doesn't help me at all. Any help, advise, or reading material that anyone could help me out with would be great.

Comment: Hi @pogeybait did you make it work? I am also trying to give an API to IOS developers in PHP for a chat application.Can you guide me or any tutorials please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you would need the extra PHP layer.
XMPP supports all the features (or most of them) you need for an IM.
You could just connect to XMPP from iOS, for example with [this library](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).

But if you insist on a PHP layer, [here are some XMPP libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/). Not just PHP, but lots of languages.

If you want to familiarize yourself with the XMPP protocols, [look here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/). They are very well documented.